# Binding combobox column to a dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, binding

I am trying to bind a combobox to a dictionary. 
"Phases" is a dictionary inside ProjectPlans class

```
 public Dictionary<decimal?, string> Phases { get; set; }
```

Instead of displaying the values, combobox shows just word "(Collection)" and no dropdown arrow. What am I missing?

```
<c1:C1DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ProjectPlans}" IsReadOnly="True" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">

    <c1:C1DataGrid.Columns>
        <c1:DataGridBoundColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ProjectId}" />
        <c1:DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="PHASE" Binding="{ Binding Phases}" DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectedValuePath="Key"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

I have found a workaround by using a DataTemplateColumn instead. But I still do not understand why it doesn't work with a DataComboBoxColumn. A bug?